# What is the average reporting delay for trades reported through a TRF?

Tags: trading, stock-exchanges, technical-analysis, trading-volume

This is a follow-up question with regards to this question:
[Nasdaq vs Nasdaq Trade Reporting Facility](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/41758/nasdaq-vs-nasdaq-trade-reporting-facility)

As well as the answer here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30366/unexplained-empty-candlestick-spikes-appear-after-large-movements

We know that an "average joe" order gets logged in the time and sales immediately when the trade happens.

However, what is the delay on TRF reported trades? Could it be as short as instantaneous, few seconds, minutes, or even hours?

I'm looking to either include or exclude these type of trades (in analyzing volume) since these singular trades can cause large volume spikes and skew data if not reported on a timely basis.

Comment: Are you asking about how long it takes venues to report to TRF or about how long it takes TRF to publish those reports?

Answer (score 1):

Transactions should be reported to the TRF within 10 seconds.  If it is reported after 10 seconds then it will be flagged as 'late'.  The transaction itself should be marked with the execution time at least in seconds, if not milliseconds.

http://www.finra.org/industry/trade-reporting-faq#101

The rules can be quite complex.