# What is a dummy buy?

Tags: stocks, shares

Trying to understand the basics of buying and selling shares by reading online lit, I just came across this in an online forum:

"Two identical buys just went through back-to-back. Anyone tried a big dummy this morning?"

Would anyone be able to explain this to me?

Comment: Can you be a little more precise about the exact trade that went through?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A **dummy trade** can mean a variety of things depending on the context, but in *no* context is it part of the "basics of buying and selling shares".  You could forget you ever heard about dummy trades and be no worse for wear.  (You could even stop reading this answer right now. :)

In any case, dummy **orders** are *far* more common than dummy **trades**, but I will explain both.  A dummy order is typically used when someone wants to test their trading software.  They'll send a buy order at a price way lower than the current highest bid (or a sell order at a price way higher than the current lowest ask) and then send a cancel request immediately thereafter.  This could be done for any number of reasons, such as testing their software, learning how fast the exchange responds, or making sure that their orders are actually getting to the lit exchange (rather than being [hijacked by their broker's dark pool](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/41595/7926)).  Sending an order far away from the current best bid/ask prices greatly reduces the possibility that the order will actually get filled during the time it takes the trader to cancel it.

(Technically speaking, sending dummy orders like this is borderline illegal because the orders are not "in good faith" -- that is, the trader has no intention of following through on the order.  However, if you do it rarely, and if you place the order so far away from the best bid/ask that nobody would possibly think it's a bona fide order in the first place, then nobody will even notice, let alone prosecute you.)

A dummy **trade** is much less common.  In the most mundane scenario a person would buy and then immediately sell (or vice versa) the smallest possible number of shares/contracts in some highly liquid symbol for the purpose of testing their software/connection to the exchange in a real trade.  This costs transaction fees and usually also the bid/ask spread on at least one of the trades, so it would be ridiculous to do it with a large block of shares/contracts.

Another reason to send a dummy trade is to "probe" the existing order book to see how much liquidity there is.  The only reason to do this, however, would be if you're trading on an unlit exchange (one that does not publish its order book).  And even in this case one would not typically send a large order.

There are plenty of more nefarious reasons for people to place dummy trades, but these all fall under the heading of market manipulation and are highly illegal.

My only conclusion is that the person you saw post that comment was simply looking for attention on an online forum.  His thought process was, "Let's post something obscure that will make people think I'm smart and have super double secret knowledge and make them envy me and treat me like a guru."  I would recommend that you ignore said person's comments and probably avoid that forum entirely if you're still just trying to learn the basics.